# Using standard file dialogs within Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I am trying to make a browse / export button in Access 2003. What I need is a command button that will allow me to browse for any file located on the computer using the standard file open dialog. Once the file has been located, I need a button to export that file to a specific location on a drive (`S:\eDNA\admin\eDNA\Engine Data`).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just a programming "spec", with no real evidence that you have done any significant research into the topic or have made any effort to solve it yourself. Please [edit] your question to show [1] the topic(s) you have searched for, and/or [2] the things you have tried and why they didn't work. If "you have no idea where to begin" then please read a book on Access or do some online tutorials and come back when you have an actual question.

Comment: So glad i came here for some help...Thanks Gord.

Comment: To keep Gord happy, I have made a simple form with a command button that allows me to search my computer for a file. This part works fine. I have made a command button to export the searched file to the specific drive as listed above but cannot seem to get it to export the file. I am unsure of how to write the code to get the searched file to export to the specific drive.

Comment: I've been using Getz/Litwin/Gilbert's code for this purpose, and I intended to post an answer accordingly, but unfortunately I'm pretty sure it's not OK to post on the web; it's also pretty awfully long. Dig up a copy of their Access Developer's Handbook maybe.

Comment: Thanks Nathan Ill do some searching for their Handbook. I have been searching everywhere to find something. Hopefully i can find their code on the web somewhere.

Comment: The main problem i have Nathan is that i have very little knowledge in writing and understanding code. Im really new to all of this.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I don't have a full answer for you as Gord makes a point, this question doesn't have a specific, answerable problem we can solve. However if you've got a bit of a handle on VBA then [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824272) explains how to display and use the standard File Dialog in Access and you can hopefully use it to make a start on your own attempt. As another aside when you're responding to someone's comment they won't be notified unless you include `@[name]` in your own comment, e.g. to get @NathanTuggy 's attention.

Comment: Thanks @Aiken. I have very little understanding of VBA, and I'm after either a code, or be pointed in the direction of a code that will make my export button send the file to the specified drive directory. I have tried numerous times to rewrite the code I have to get it to send the file, with no success.

Comment: It would help potential answerers a lot if you edited your question to include what you've tried so far (as in the code), what you expect it to do, what it actually does and any errors that occur. See [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more guidelines on what sort of code to include

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to do is **copy** a file from your local drive to a network drive, not **export** it.  In order to do that, add this to your code:

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

Then you could use

```
fso.CopyFile(source, destination[, overwrite] )
```

You should be able to capture both the source and the destination from the Standard Dialogue forms.